# App Engine can't update "The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota" new version is deleted

Tags: google-app-engine

I have this annoying error with App Engine; basically our platforms usualy have 2-3 services running on them using Docker container with Flex 'custom' set.

Flex 'custom' uses 2 instances by default. The default quota limit is 4.

When we deploy 2 services we reach the limit; once we've reached the limit we have no way of updating the old versions of the app; we get rejected with "The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota" even for updating the exsiting service.

Also the new version gets deleted from App Engine 'versions' so right now we've locked out; we can't update the app, we can't delete it and we can't even stop it as it's the default we're trying to update.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, you got these 2 services and then you deployed 2 different ones, after that you are not able to deploy updated versions of the 2 services you began with, is this correct? What kind of quota do you have, daily or per-minute?

Comment: @RafaelLemos yes I cannot update cause I need 2 more resources to update :-/ I have two standard services (frontend and backend)

Comment: Not an ideal thing, but what if you were to stop you older versions services with `gcloud app versions stop VERSIONS` and then deploy a new version? This could allow you to deploy updates without the need of new instance, there would be, however, some down time.